# Unable to access xml response node using xpath in apache camel

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I am Not able to access an below XML response node using below stated `xpath` syntax.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetHolidayDateResponse xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">
         <GetHolidayDateResult>2019-01-01T00:00:00</GetHolidayDateResult>
      </GetHolidayDateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried below syntax for `xpath`:

```
<setHeader headerName="HolidayResult" id="_setHeader2">
    <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">*/GetHolidayDateResponse/GetHolidayDateResult/text()</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

I want to `GetHolidayDateResult` node from above stated XML response.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `//GetHolidayDateResponse/GetHolidayDateResult/text()`

Comment: Also mind about namespaces, as xpath is very picky about this